# Open selected text in new tab

Tags: autohotkey

What I have is this:

```
; Search Cntl+Shift+c

^+c::
{
    Send, ^c
    Sleep 50
    Run "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "%clipboard%"
    return
}
```

What I get is kind of correct. Basically when I highlight a link I can quickly open it, but it does not work with regular text.

If I mark text and want to do a quick search on the other tab, it actually redirects me to http://text.

What I want is to just past the clipboard on the taskbar at the top and then let Firefox do the work
(decide if it is a link or if it is a normal text, in which case it just redirects it to the search engine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have/use Firefox, but I'd assume it has shortcuts to open a new tab just like any other browser would. So maybe good to make use to those.
I'd assume CTRL+T creates and activates a new tab and the search field in it, so I'll write an example script for that:

```
^+c::
    Clipboard := "" ;empty clipboard
    SendInput, ^c
    ClipWait, 2 ;wait (max 2 secs) for clipboard to contain something
    if (Clipboard != "") ;if we got something to the Clipboard
        SendInput, ^t^v{Enter} ;CTRL+T CTRL+V Enter
return
```

Used [`ClipWait`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ClipWait.htm) instead of `Sleep`ing and switched over to [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) due to it being faster and more reliable.
Works just fine for me (on Google Chrome). One possible issue I could see, is it being too fast and your computer being slow. If that were to be the case, switch over to using normal `Send` and use [`SetKeyDelay`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm).

Comment: Wow that was pretty easy. Thanks you.